# Cutting Digits from Integer

Tags: java, int

I am working on a project and I am stuck at a problem where I want to cut some values down to 8 Digits for my Output.

My idea was to get the value by the Loop at the beginning, transfer them to a String and cut the String according to the numbers needed, only the first 8 digits are important.

Can somebody help me why I get a Index.outOfBoundException?
Thank you very much in advance!

```
    public int Addup(int color)
{
    //Checking what is missing 
    int diff = 8 / bitdepth;
    int calc = color;

    //Anfang der Berechnung 
    for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
    {
        calc = color +(int) (color * Math.pow(2, bitdepth));
    }

    System.out.print(calc);
    String convert = Integer.toString(calc);
    convert = convert.substring(0, 7);

    System.out.println(convert);

    return calc;
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen if `convert` has fewer than 7 characters?  And what do you think _would_ happen in that case, based on the [Javadoc of the `substring` method of `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)?

Comment: Well, the loop is responsible for filling my variable with the numbers until it reaches 8 or more so there are alway more than 7 characters...

Comment: Why do you think that?  I can think of all sorts of ways that loop might stop before there are 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are not currently ensuring that you have at least eight digits before your substring call. You could use a formatting output with leading zeros. You are also only taking seven characters currently. For eight you need something like

```
String convert = String.format("%08d", calc).substring(0, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The Loop only ends when my variable has more than 7 digits so I am not sure if I need to check it again here. Can you maybe explain me why you included the "%08d" Part?

Comment: The zero `08` means use zero to pad (with leading zeros), the eight in `08` means pad to a minimum of eight digits.